# String as a sentinel in while loop in C++

Tags: c++, input, getchar

I've tried to make a function that reads short lines from standard input using `getchar()`. The function works really well itself, but when I use it as a part of a sentinel in a while loop I'm always getting an error that, in short, says that it cannot convert from string to bool.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
string myReadLine();
int main()
{
string str = "";
while ((str = myReadLine()) != NULL) { //eof, and any expression of that sort

cout << str << endl;

}
    return 0;
}




string myReadLine() {
string line =  "";
char singleSign;

while ((singleSign=getchar()) != '\n') {
line = line + singleSign;

}
return line;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'll appreciate any help from You!

Question 2:
What do You think about efficiency of `myReadLine()` function? Is it okay?

Comment: `while ((str = myReadLine() != NULL)` is simply invalid... Maybe you mean `while ((str = myReadLine()) != NULL)`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Of course, my bad! That was unintentional. But might be the core problem?

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you can't convert a string to a bool. I suggest:

```
str = myReadLine();
while (!str.empty())                                         
{
  cout << str << endl;
  str = myReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank U very much, for some simple ussage it works very well, but what could be wrong if after first iteration, compilator  says that i've extended time limit?

Comment: I don't know. What are you feeding to standard input?

Answer (score 1):

In this line (assuming you incorrectly typed an extra parentheses in there):

```
while (str = myReadLine() != NULL)
```

The `myReadLine() != NULL` is being evaluated before `str = myReadLine()`. That's why it's saying `str` can't be converted to a `bool`.

put a parentheses around the `str = myReadLine()` and it should work.

```
while (str = myReadLine()) != NULL)
```

Comment: Tahk u, but I've made a little mistype, what might be the core problem anyway?

Comment: You've used it and it doesn't work the way you want it to? I'd rewrite my answer but Beta's answer below seems to solve your problem as well.

Comment: @vladimir1923 `myReadLine()` returns a string, but you're comparing it with `NULL`, which is a macro which expands to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison of instance of class string with NULL is incorrect. You could do this with a pointers.

It is a next best way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
bool myReadLine(string& line);
int main()
{
string str = "";
while (myReadLine(str)){

cout << str << endl;

}
    return 0;
}


bool myReadLine(string& line) {
char singleSign;
line = "";

while ((singleSign=getchar()) != '\n') {
line = line + singleSign;

}
return line == "" ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, that looks very nice, I wouldn't came up with this idea. But what must be wrong that when I paste this snippet of code to ideone.com and I put a few short lines of data I receive an answer but in addition I get an error that I exeeded time limit. What might me wrong?

Comment: And second question: how exactly this function work? How come it gives a return line if there's a boolean expression at the end of it?

Comment: About time limit exceeded:
[Look here](https://ideone.com/files/ideone-api.pdf)
time limit exceeded – the program didn't stop before 
the time limit

Comment: About how it work. std::string it is a class. We can pass pointer or reference to a class in a function in two ways:
 - myReadLine(string& line) -> by reference
 - myReadLine(string* pLine) -> like a pointer
So in this case we pass the same class instance and it can be modified in our function without returning a value of class.

Comment: Thank u for this but I still have a problem with getting it. Which point in the function returns line? When I pasted this code to code::blocks and compiled either after pasting a few lines or after typing one line and pressing enter the only output are numbers -1 -1 or similar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I've figured out the precise way the function works, but I still don't get why I have problem of time limit exceeding on any compilers including the one in code::blocks or in spoj.com. What can I do to overcome this?